# How to calculate the right path for this spaceship?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

a spaceship is moving with velocity $v$ in a line, it has a distance P with a planet with $$F=-(mγ)/r^3 
(γ=8/9 P^2v^2)$$

[image: the image]

now, how can I show this spaceship turns around the planet B for 1 round, and its closest distance to the planet B, and its velocity at that point.

As far as I know we should use the $F=ma$
then from a evaluate $r, θ$ if in polar coordinates, or something like this.
what I get is:
$$r(θ)=1/[C1 sin(ωθ)+C2cos(ωθ)]$$
for ω= radical (1-mμ/L^2)
but the constants C1 & C2 can't be found.
how can I solve what is been asked?

Answer (score 0):

The Equation of motions are:

$$m\,\ddot r-m\,\dot\theta^2\,r+F_r=0\\
r^2\,\ddot\theta+r\,2\dot r\dot\theta=0\quad\Rightarrow\\
\dot\theta=\frac{h}{r^2}$$

where $~F_r=\frac{m\,\gamma}{r^3}$

form here you obtain

$$r(\theta)=\left[C_1\sin(\omega\,\theta)+C_2\cos(\omega\,\theta)\right]^{-1}$$

where $~\omega=\frac{\sqrt{h^2-\gamma}}{h}\quad $

The Initial conditions

$$r\,\sin(\theta)\bigg|_{\theta=\pi/2}=p\\
\frac{dr}{d\theta}\bigg|_{\theta=0}=0$$

I got this result ?

[image]